# Lightbook of pictures like on behance. js/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

How create popup with url like on behance. If picture is open from the main page then it looks like popup, but with url. https://www.behance.net/
And if i use picture's url, it is page. https://www.behance.net/gallery/19074521/editorial-illustration-2014-2

```
$('a[data-popup]').on 'click', ->
  @url = $(this).data('path')
  $.ajax
    url: @url
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'html'
    success: (data) ->
      $('.pop-up').show()
      $('.pop-up').html(data)
  $('.backdrop').on 'click', ->
    $('.pop-up').hide()
  $('.close').on 'click', ->
    $('.pop-up').hide()
    $('.white-container').show()

doctype html
html
head
//
body
 .container
   .wrap
     = yield
       .pop-up
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not currently using a framework that includes client-side routing as a feature, then maybe try [Director](https://github.com/flatiron/director#client-side-routing).  It's a pretty simple solution that I have used in a CoffeeScript project.